The Era of Judges was Transient; Why Does the Ramban Need Samson's Untimely Death to Prove That This Era was not an Enduring Epoch of God's Salvation?
Jacob in Genesis 49 states:

לִישׁוּעָתְךָ, קִוִּיתִי יְהוָה. For Your salvation I await, Lord.

Per the Ramban, Jacob repudiates Samson and the epoch of Judges.


יח
לישועתך קויתי ה' לא היה בכל שופטי ישראל מי שנפל ביד אויביו זולתי שמשון שהוא הנחש הזה כדכתיב (שופטים ב יח) והיה ה' עם השופט והושיעם מיד אויביהם כל ימי השופט והוא היה האחרון לשופטים כי שמואל נביא היה ולא נלחם להם ובימיו מלכו המלכים וכאשר ראה הנביא תשועת שמשון כי נפסקה אמר לישועתך קויתי ה' לא לישועת נחש ושפיפון כי בך אושע לא בשופט כי תשועתך תשועת עולמים:

I HOPE FOR THY AID, O ETERNAL. Among all the judges of Israel there was none who fell into the hands of his enemies except Samson, who is this “snake” [referred to in Jacob’s prophecy], just as it is written, Then the Eternal was with the judge, and saved them out of the hand of their enemies all the days of the judge, and Samson was the last of the judges since his successor Samuel was a prophet and he did not conduct war on the people’s behalf, and in his days the kings [Saul and David] reigned. Now when the prophet Jacob saw that the deliverance which was to come through Samson ceased [when he died together with the Philistines], he said, “I hope for Thy aid, O Eternal, not for the aid of ‘the snake’ or ‘the serpent,’ for it is by Thee that I will be helped, not by a judge, as Thy salvation is ‘an everlasting salvation.’”

What does the Ramban exactly mean by י והיה ה' עם השופט והושיעם מיד אויביהם כל ימי השופט והוא היה האחרון לשופטים ?
Is he saying that since Samson died an untimely death which is inimical to "the Eternal was with the judge, and saved them out of the hand of their enemies all the days of the judge" and since Samson was the last of the Judges this means that Samson in particular, and the Judges in general, were not the stuff of God's salvation?
If so, what if Samson lived and not fallen into enemy hands (a la the other judges)? Would this have changed Jacob's mind about Samson and Judges? Why? Jacob would still realize that Judges are not messianic kings who usher in an era of permanent salvation of God because presumably he knows per the Ramban that Samuel ushers in a new and different era of prophets.
How does this Ramban exactly read?

Saw this answer in a Shivlei Pinches our Shmuel brought the other day, that Yaacov saw Shimshon destroy the 50th gate of Tumah stronghold, the temple of Dagon, and thought he was Moshiach, but then he died which proved he wasn't Moshiach because Moshiach will destroy it permanently and reach the 50th gate of Kedusha without dying

I think your question assumes that Samson's fate was a sad accident, and the Ramban assumes that it was hashgacha, and proof that the system of Judges was ultimately flawed and incapable of complete success.
